# Using my iMac in a country with a different power supply standard

Tags: imac, internationalization, power

We may be relocating to a different area of the world where the power standards and outlets differ considerably from what I've got here in North America.

Is the power supply in my iMac auto-adjusting, universal? Can I just buy a new IEC cable for it to match the local plug standard and run it straight in to the wall? Or do I need a transformer?

Edit: I have an older iMac. 2007. 2.8 GHz Core 2 Duo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on @penguinrob's answer, the specs for the 2007 iMac can be found on the [Apple Support KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP16):

> **Electrical and environmental requirements**
>
> Meets ENERGY STAR requirements
>
> - Line voltage: 100-240V
> - AC Frequency:
>     50Hz to 60Hz, single phase
> - Maximum continuous power: 200W (20-inch
>     models); 280W (24-inch model)
> - Operating temperature: 50° to 95° F (10°
>     to 35° C)
> - Storage temperature: -40° to 185° F (-40° to 85° C)
> - Relative
>     humidity: 5% to 95% noncondensing
> - Maximum altitude: 10,000 feet

It looks like you should be able to get by with the IEC cable/adapter; the transformer can handle 100-240V, so you likely do not need an additional transformer.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.apple.com/imac/specs.html (under Electrical and Operating Requirements), it specifies a line voltage of 100-240V AC, so if the country you're going to provides plugs with output in that voltage range, you should be fine.

According to http://web.archive.org/web/20071025020751/http://www.apple.com/imac/specs.html (snapshot of the imac tech specs page from October 2007, the same voltage requirements apply.

Comment: That's for the latest gen iMac -- mines much older. Does it still apply?

Comment: Awesome. Looks like it'll work. Thanks. Or maybe not....now I can't justify a new one. ;)

Comment: @IanC. - depends on how much you can sell your old one for. :)

Comment: Yes - all intel iMacs (and most iMacs [except some few G5 models sold in the US, Canada and Japan](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1981)) have auto-switching power supplies. All iSight iMacs too are auto-switching. As long as your mains aren't at 400v or 400 Hz you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It's not what you asked, but <sub><sup>(at least some of)</sup></sub> the G5 and G4 iMacs **do not** support different power supply standards.

I know this, because a co-worker tried plugging a 120V one into a 240V UPS, and it almost caught fire.

<sub><sup>To make the situation even more amusing/tragilarious, he did this **twice**. Only one of the computers he blew up was an iMac, though.</sup></sub>

Comment: And those vintage power supplies STUNK TO HIGH HEAVEN when they blew in the PPC iMacs. Good thing they were so simple to pop in and out again. (and the system almost always survived the jolt unscathed)

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: I personally +1 it since it's very relevant to the wider question, but a lot more voting and people are here so I can only guess they took your expansion of the literal question as noise rather than related...

Answer (score -1):

No problem re getting an adapter and usung the iMac, BUT instead of directly into the wall, plug it into a power surge bar as some countries have more “ebb and flow” than in North Merica.